# How do I call a function with in a function?

Tags: javascript, optimization

I need to add i3c to my and statements.  I don't know the correct syntax. This code is broken.  Would an anonymous function be better?  So if c0() passes, c4() runs, if c4() passes I need i3c() to run or what is in i3c to run.

```
function o1(a,b)
  {
  document.getElementById(a).value=b;
  }
function i3()
  {
  var a=document.forms['f3'].elements,b='f3e';
  c0(a,'Please enter both a tile and a url',b)&&c4(a[2],'Please enter a valid url',b)&&d0()&&s0('pi3a.php',is('f3'),s2);
  o1(f3aa,'');o1(f3bb,'');
  }
function d0()
  {
  var a=document.getElementById('Bb1c'),
  b=document.createElement('a'),
  c=document.forms['f3'].elements;  
  b.href=c[2].value;
  b.name="a1";    
  b.className ="b";
  b.innerHTML = c[1].value; 
  a.appendChild(b);
  return 1;
  }
```

Comment: What... the... hell?

Comment: what you pass is the reference, not the function call..that is a mess

Comment: I have got no idea what this code is trying to do. For the sake of your sanity, give your functions and variables meaningful names so that you know what they do.

Comment: FYI: `c.setAttribute("class","b");` will break IE6. You'd need `"className"` instead.

Comment: If this is not a joke then it must be the worst piece of code i have ever seen ever

Comment: I wish I could vote Platinum Azure up more then once....

Comment: Real men read minimized code.

Comment: No. Real men have the guts to put their uncensored code on SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function i3() {
    var e = 'f3e';
    if ( !(c0(a,'Please enter both a tile and a url',e)) ) { return flase; }
    if ( !(c4(a[2],'Please enter a valid url',b)) ) { return flase; }
    (function() {
        var doc = document,
            a = doc.forms.f3.elements,
            b = doc.getElementById('Bb1c'),
            c = doc.createElement('a'),
            d = doc.forms.f3.elements;
        c.href = d[2].value;
        c.name = "a1";
        c.className = "b";
        c.innerHTML = d[1].value;
        b.appendChild(c);
        // which a you need here ???
        //var a = is('f3');
        var someOtherA = is('f3');
        //------------------------
        s0('pi3a.php', a, s2);
        // if these are part of the form you use in this function
        // use 
        // document.forms[<name>].elements[<name>].value
        doc.getElementById('f3aa').value = '';
        doc.getElementById('f3bb').value = '';
    })();
}
```

This may work, I suppose c0 and c4 return true/false. This way they are easier to read. If they return true, continue with the next one and don`t return.

In the i3c function you declare **a** twice!

Look at the comments for more details.

Comment: I think this is what I was looking for.  There is no reason to name a function if it is only used once.  I was told on a previous post that using AND statments is a micro-optimization over if statements.

Comment: @Chris Aaker it is good for production, but for development, as I say it is better - tracking errors etc.

Comment: Woa, actually an unnamed function takes up more space with all the extra snytax, then if you use a "minimized" function name. .

Answer (score 1):

The && (logical AND operator) is processed left to right. If any expression returns false, that value is returned. If all but the last one return true, then the value of the last expression is returned (whether it is true or false).

So if *i3c* is not being called, it is because the return value of one of the preceding calls is falsey, i.e. it type converts to false, so it might be 0, '' (empty string), undefined, NaN, null, ... I've probably left one out.

#### Edit

As patrick w commented, the line:

```
  c.setAttribute("class","b");
```

will fail in IE. Don't use *setAttribute* for standard attributes, use DOM properties instead:

```
c.href = d[2].value;   
c.name = "a1";   
c.className = "b";
```

Faster and less bugy.